# Error with the linux/unix command.permission denied

Tags: linux, unix

When I enter the following command in my mac OSX terminal i get a "permission denied" error even though I have administrative privileges.

**Command:**

```
administrators-Mac-mini-2:Build Foldername sarwan$ ./dpkg-scanpackages -m . /dev/null --> Packages
```

**Error:**

```
-bash: ./dpkg-scanpackages: Permission denied
```

**EDIT:**
The Build I am trying to make is for an ios project thats why I included the iphone tag.I don't know if that helps or not.

**EDIT 2**
Thanks Gryphius your answer is correct.

Comment: check if the file dpkg-scanpackes is executable

Comment: @Gryphius write your answer in the answers section so that I can choose it as the correct Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a file is not executable you get this error even with administrative privileges. make your script executable and it should work

```
[root@boscos gryphius]# echo 'echo hello world!' > mytestscript.sh
[root@boscos gryphius]# ./mytestscript.sh
bash: ./mytestscript.sh: Permission denied
[root@boscos gryphius]# chmod 755 mytestscript.sh 
[root@boscos gryphius]# ./mytestscript.sh 
hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite being logged in with administrative privileges, you usually need to use sudo at least once before you are granted these privileges through terminal (at least thats what I've found).

Try "sudo Build SGService sarwan$ ./dpkg-scanpackages -m . /dev/null --> Packages"

-Nick

Comment: I rather think `sudo` should be put in front of the real command, not in front of the prompt (which is, admittedly, not separated in a very readable way)...